# How to setState of a particular index in an array React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have an array of objects that I am currently mapping over to generate as buttons. When clicked, I want the background color of the specific button the user clicks on to change color ( I want it to toggle on, like a switch, so I can eventually save to async storage).  Right now when the user clicks, all buttons change color.  I'm not quite sure how I should handle this.setState in the selectMetric function.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';

const RISK_DATA = [
  {id: 1, text: 'cats', flag: false, buttonColor: null},
  {id: 2, text: 'dogs', flag: false, buttonColor: null},

]


class IssueSelectionScreen extends Component {

  state = {flag: false, buttonColor: null}

  selectMetric = (index) => {

    for (let i=0; i < RISK_DATA.length; i++) {

      if (index === (RISK_DATA[i].id - 1)) {

      console.log("RISK_DATA:", RISK_DATA[i]); // logs matching id

// ------------------------------------------------------
// Problem setting correct state here:

      RISK_DATA[i].buttonColor = this.setState({flag: true, buttonColor: '#03A9F4'})

      // this.setState({flag: true, buttonColor: '#03A9F4'})
      // this.setState({update(this.state.buttonColor[i], {buttonColor: {$set: '#03A9F4'}}) })


// ----------------------------------------------------------
      }
    }
  }

  showMetric() {
    return RISK_DATA.map((metric, index) => {
      return (
        <View key={metric.id}>
          <Button
            raised
            color={'black'}
            title={metric.text}
            borderRadius={12}
            onPress={() => this.selectMetric(index)}
            backgroundColor={this.state.buttonColor}
          >
            {metric.text}
          </Button>
          <Text>{/* intentionally blank*/} </Text>
        </View>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.wrapper}>
        <View style={styles.issues}>
          {this.showMetric()}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


const styles = {
  issues: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  wrapper: {
    backgroundColor: '#009688'
  }
}

export default IssueSelectionScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the short answer to your question would look something like this:

```
class IssueSelectionScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: cloneDeep(RISK_DATA),
    };
  }

  selectMetric = (index) => {
    const tempData = cloneDeep(this.state.data);
    tempData[index].flag = !tempData[index].flag;
    this.setState({ data: tempData });
  }

  showMetric() {
    return this.state.data.map((metric, index) => {
      // same
    })
  }

  render() {
    // same
  }
}
```

It involves putting the whole array of buttons into state since the state of those buttons is what can change.  You could also maintain the flags as an array in state and keep the button info as a separate constant

This solution uses cloneDeep (from lodash) to prevent the code from mutating the state of the objects but you could probably also do it with `this.state.data.map` and creating new objects (which works as long as your objects aren't deeply nested).

If you're using Redux, the list would probably come into the component as a prop, then selectMetric would be dispatching an action to update the flag in Redux.

Comment: Thanks Garrett, really Helpful!

Comment: I noticed it doesn't scale to well with datasets (20+).  The button has about a one second delay when changing color.  Any tips on scalability for this component?

Comment: I'd try a FlatList instead of a ScrollView/map on Array.  If you do a map on the Array, the entire thing re-renders for every change.  FlatList has optimizations to prevent unnecessary renders.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else viewing this post, the answer above is very helpful. To add a few last remarks, if you're trying to get the buttons to light up I added a simple if else to selectMetric:

```
if (tempData[index].flag) {
  tempData[index].buttonColor = '#03A9F4';
  console.log('tempData true:', tempData);
} else {
  tempData[index].buttonColor = null;
  console.log('tempData false:', tempData);
}
```

and updated the backgroundColor property on Button in showMetric with:

```
backgroundColor={this.state.data[index].buttonColor}
```